# Changing request protocol restsdk

Tags: c++, windows, request, protocols, cpprest-sdk

So I want to add support for all protocols when doing a request with the rest sdk. This is the default protocols supported for Windows:

> By default only SSL3 and TLS1 are enabled in Windows 7 and Windows 8. By default only SSL3, TLS1.0, TLS1.1, and TLS1.2 are enabled in Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.

Before creating the request, I set up a http_client_config and create a callback for set_nativehandle_options, which looks like this:

```
std::function<void(web::http::client::native_handle)> get_callback()
{
    auto func = [&](const web::http::client::native_handle handle)
    {
        std::cout << "handle: " << std::hex << handle << std::endl;
        DWORD secure_protocols = WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_ALL;
        if (!WinHttpSetOption(handle, WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURE_PROTOCOLS, &secure_protocols, sizeof(secure_protocols)))
        {
            std::cout << "Can not set WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_ALL" << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::dec << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        }
        else
            std::cout << "Set WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_ALL" << std::endl;
    };

    return func;
}
```

So basically the issue is that WinHttpSetOption always returns ERROR_INTERNET_INCORRECT_HANDLE_TYPE. Unfortunately that contradicts with the statement on [this](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1http_1_1client_1_1http__client__config.html) website:

> The native_handle is the following type depending on the underlying platform: Windows Desktop, WinHTTP - HINTERNET Windows Runtime, WinRT - IXMLHTTPRequest2 * ....

I found a [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/issues/76) addressing this issue, but it seems like it was never resolved.

Perhaps anyone has an idea what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Okay well seems like the function is just broken. I just hooked WinHttpOpen which returns the handle I am supposed to use and the function worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

This should works fine

```
web::http::client::http_client_config GetHttpConfig()
{
    web::http::client::http_client_config config;
    
    auto func = [&](web::http::client::native_handle handle) {
        HINTERNET hSession = WinHttpOpen(L"TestApp",
            WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
            WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
            WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

        DWORD secure_protocols = WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_ALL;

        if (!WinHttpSetOption(hSession, WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURE_PROTOCOLS, &secure_protocols, sizeof(secure_protocols)))
        {
            std::cout << "Can not set WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_ALL" << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::dec << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Set WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_ALL" << std::endl;
            handle = hSession;
        }        
    };

    config.set_nativehandle_options(func);
    return config;
}
```